# BSPMapGen demo blurry on html5 target

Tags: haxeflixel

I can't get the BSPMapGen demo to look like it does on the official html5 demo page, the `fillRect` function seems to create antialiased pixels in the BitmapData.
I'm running the demo as-is with no changes.